# If $\zeta_n$ is the $nth$ root of unity, find $\dim_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb Q[\zeta_n]$

Tags: vector-spaces, roots-of-unity

For $n=1,2,3,4$ I found it to be $1,1,2,2$ respectively. So I hypothesize that $\dim_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb Q[\zeta_{2n}]=n$  and $\dim_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb Q[\zeta_{2n+1}]=n+1$.
But how to prove it?
When we have $2n$, the roots lie on the vertices of a regular $2n-$gon centred at $0$. The roots occur in pairs; placed on the extremities of a diagonal through $0$. So the dimension is no more than $n$, since half of them are simply scalar multiples of the other half.

But this is all I got. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "*The* $n$th root of unity" does not make sense. $1$ is a $n$th root of unity for any $n$. You probably meant "a primitive $n$th root of unity".

Comment: Try $n=5$......

Answer (score 1):

When $n=6$, the sixth roots of unity are the cube roots of
unity and their negatives, so that $\Bbb Z(\zeta_6)=\Bbb Z(\zeta_3)$ which has degree $2$ over $\Bbb Q$. That rather puts the kibosh on your conjecture.

The minimum polynomial of $\zeta_n$ is called the $n$-th
[cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

Comment: ... and the dimension the author is looking for is $\varphi(n)$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function